# {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "No matching code found."}

Tags: http-status-code-400

When I try to get my API access token I get the following message:

> {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "No
>   matching code found."}

Am I doing something wrong? (I've found some other people with the same issue, but no real solution)

this is what i do (the code i got was retrieved in the normal way):

```
curl \-F 'client_id=54abf4780ba243709a4feca5de6eddc3' \
-F 'client_secret=c00b41a176ebb169ae985b234b9a1cb1' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=http://www.rubenvandervleuten.com/accesstoken' \
-F 'code=e608b548d0f64de56dd11895c02af99b8' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

Comment: if it is real client id & secret then don't expose it here.....

Comment: it's has some changed figures so not usable

Comment: Have you ever had luck with getting it?

Comment: I kept on having issues but used this one: http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token#access_token=35335669.da21241.e00e66c2cacc4af4876f63bf7ac49c60. But I just read that it is offline so can't help you at this point. I'm sorry